# Auto-scrolling a PDF on a page basis with Foxit Reader 7

Tags: windows-7, pdf, scrolling, foxit-reader

Is it possible to auto-scroll a PDF on a page basis with Foxit Reader 7 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate? By page basis I mean I want the PDF to auto-scroll page by page, and not by small increments which is the default behavior when selecting "AutoScroll":

[image]

I am aware that I can use some external the programs to take care of that ( e.g. AHK ), but I want to know whether Foxit Reader 7 has this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to auto-scroll a PDF on a page basis with Foxit Reader 7.